# Responsive layout - 4 sprites in a row, stretch/shrink to enclosure

Tags: html, css

I have 4 images and I'd like them to dynamically resize so they are always shown on one row with no gaps (that is, all 4 should always take up the full width of the enclosing DIV, regardless of how wide/narrow that DIV is).

Example code is here: http://codepen.io/pnoeric/pen/YGXOJb

```css
.enclosure {
  width: 532px;    // arbitrary size - could be '100%' or '312px'
  border: solid 2px red;
}
.sprite {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
}
/*
       all sample images are 100x30
    */

.s1 {
  background: url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTqwGCIaDwDynzLuM-YQaf6hbKOrPZ7X5kPbBXeG2xONmjg7wQAhw');
}
.s2 {
  background: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSSZ7q4ghxvj5iOSHtJCf0UHMbh_JFnLLJEKH4kqtDfcB70-1T_jA');
}
.s3 {
  background: url('https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTjcLooOn0vKrelH5ecjYIFYSEKl2AE64VqoLcxtyBRnzESArTKFg');
}
.s4 {
  background: url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTTorTZRr54yI3fsL-X6xtXfnkbtATCqWF_ZIWF9g4QvsPg5g09');
}
```

```html
<h3>
      THE GOAL: get each image below to stretch (or shrink) to
      fill enclosure with no gaps... example here should have
      each image stretch to 133px (532 / 4) 
    </h3>

<div class='enclosure'>
  <div class='sprite s1'></div>
  <div class='sprite s2'></div>
  <div class='sprite s3'></div>
  <div class='sprite s4'></div>
</div>
```

Is this possible? Or do I need to go back to `<img>` tags and some kind of table?

Comment: You've given them a fixed width. Why would you expect them to flex?

Comment: Ammm I have another definition for sprites .... those seems just individual imgs.

Comment: @isherwood - so it sounds like you're talking about a solution. ;-) How would I go about getting them to stretch?

Comment: @danip - yes, as I mention in a comment above, in the real code I pull all the backgrounds from one image (i.e. proper CSS sprites).

Comment: This sounds like you are trying to size the div height to the background image and that's not possible

Comment: Umm I see then you need to put the real code here, there is a huge difference between using just one img for bg and position it and use individual images .... I know a solution if you use individual imgs but if it's a sprite changing the position I can't test it

Comment: Ok-- hmmm for now let's assume I'm using individual images like the sample code above... can you post your solution? In fact I'm going to edit my question to remove all the "sprite" stuff... let's just assume I have 4 individual images!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want responsiveness, you should use percentage for the sizes.

```css
.enclosure {
  width:500px;    // arbitrary size - could be '100%'
  border:solid 2px red;
}

.sprite {
  float:left;
  width:25%;
  height:30px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
  background-size: 100% 100% !important; /* you can use other options like cover */
}

/* all sample sprites are 100x30 images -- yes in the real code I actually pull them all from one background image, like real CSS sprites :-) */

.s1 { background: url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTqwGCIaDwDynzLuM-YQaf6hbKOrPZ7X5kPbBXeG2xONmjg7wQAhw'); }

.s2 { background:url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSSZ7q4ghxvj5iOSHtJCf0UHMbh_JFnLLJEKH4kqtDfcB70-1T_jA'); }

.s3 { background:url('https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTjcLooOn0vKrelH5ecjYIFYSEKl2AE64VqoLcxtyBRnzESArTKFg'); }

.s4 { background:url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTTorTZRr54yI3fsL-X6xtXfnkbtATCqWF_ZIWF9g4QvsPg5g09'); }
```

```html
<div class='enclosure'>
  <div class='sprite s1'></div>
  <div class='sprite s2'></div>
  <div class='sprite s3'></div>
  <div class='sprite s4'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I apologize if I wasn't more clear in my original question -- my goal is to have each individual graphic stretch or contract to fill all the available space. I want all 4 next to each other (no gaps). I've clarified the question to make this more clear.

Comment: @Eric, then use my updated answer. I changed the background-size

Comment: @Eric Ammm there is just one problem here ... now change to 100% the width of the container. The bg images will be streched not proportional

Comment: @Eric, that's impossible to make it proper. Because the background image would be matched with the size of the div.sprite. When you are using the image as background, you have some limitations. Otherwise, you have to use <img> tag instead of background. In this case, the background tries to fit 30px in height as the div is

Comment: @DaniP, how come? when the div size is fixed by pixel and the div sizes are not proper, how do you do that?

Comment: @DaniP, I don't see fixed height for the div on your answer

Comment: Because you don't need that to make it proportional just make the scale proportion with the padd-top value

Comment: @DaniP, that's the point I said. It's impossible to have no proper fixed sizes and make the background proper. Let's finish this argue

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Let's see maybe it works too with a vertical sprite but you will have to test it.</sub>

---

If you have individual images you will need to include this tips:

- The use of `background-size:contain` that way we can cover all the dinamic space.
- Make use of `%` units for the containers in order to keep proportion

Please review this code:

```css
.enclosure {
  border:solid 2px red;
}
/*Add the clear for the floated elements*/
.enclosure:after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
.sprite {
  float:left;
  /*Use % for your dimensions all inline 25%*/
  width:25%;
  /*This padding keeps the proportion of the original size 100x30*/
  padding-top:7.5%;
  background:url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTqwGCIaDwDynzLuM-YQaf6hbKOrPZ7X5kPbBXeG2xONmjg7wQAhw') no-repeat center;
  background-size:contain;
}
.s1 { background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTqwGCIaDwDynzLuM-YQaf6hbKOrPZ7X5kPbBXeG2xONmjg7wQAhw'); }
.s2 { background-image:url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSSZ7q4ghxvj5iOSHtJCf0UHMbh_JFnLLJEKH4kqtDfcB70-1T_jA'); }
.s3 { background-image:url('https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTjcLooOn0vKrelH5ecjYIFYSEKl2AE64VqoLcxtyBRnzESArTKFg'); }
.s4 { background-image:url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTTorTZRr54yI3fsL-X6xtXfnkbtATCqWF_ZIWF9g4QvsPg5g09'); }
```

```html
<div class='enclosure'>
  <div class='sprite s1'></div>
  <div class='sprite s2'></div>
  <div class='sprite s3'></div>
  <div class='sprite s4'></div>
</div>
```